# reiniciar Socket al ocurrir excepcion

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un servicio que recibe eventos por `TCP`, al ocurrir una excepción en el método `ClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)` se me cierra la aplicación, y al controlar la excepción con un `try catch` no se cierra la aplicación pero no me permite que de esa `ip` sigan llegando eventos.

Lo que quiero es que al ocurrir una excepción se me reinicie el `socket`, por que al cerrar y abrir el servicio todo sigue funcionando normal.

```
internal void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
        try
        {
            // Increment our ConcurrentConnections counter
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentConnections);

            // So we can buffer and store information, create a new information class
            SocketConnectionInfo connection = new SocketConnectionInfo();
            connection.Buffer = new byte[SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize];

            // We want to end the async event as soon as possible
            Socket asyncListener = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            Socket asyncClient = asyncListener.EndAccept(asyncResult);

            // Set the SocketConnectionInformations socket to the current client
            connection.Socket = asyncClient;

            // Tell anyone that's listening that we have a new client connected
            if (OnClientConnected != null)
            {
                OnClientConnected(this, null);
            }

            // TODO :: Add throttleling (using SEMAPHORE's)

            // Begin recieving the data from the client
            if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP)
            {
                asyncClient.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
            }
            else if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP)
            {
                asyncClient.BeginReceiveFrom(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ipeSender, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
            }
            // Now we have begun recieving data from this client,
            // we can now accept a new client
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ClientConnected), listener);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("HighPerformanceServer: Exception metodo ClientConnected ->" + e.Message);
           Stop();

        }

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que parte del codigo es la que produce la excepcion? Me parece que solo tienes que volver a declarar el socket en la parte donde va el cach. aunque seria bueno saber porque se produce la excepcion, porque eso te puede producir mas problemas.

Comment: exactamente no se donde ocurre por que son muchos equipos que realizan peticiones a este servicio y esta en un ambiente de producción, ademas ocurre cuando le da la gana. Se ha hecho la declaración del socket y no se cae el servicio pero ya no permite que ese equipo siga enviando eventos. Solo se soluciona al cerrar y volver a abrir el servicio.

Comment: Y el catch que imprime cuando captura el error? o tampoco puedes ver eso?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta con la imagen de la ecepcion.

Comment: Hola, puedes poner el código de como invocas al método ClientConnected()?